# How can I avoid this deadlock in DevForce when using interceptors

Tags: c#, multithreading, deadlock, devforce

We have recently started taking our business logic that relies heavily on DevForce and exposing it over a web API.  We have been very careful to avoid threading issues by ensuring each request has its own set of entities, its own `EntityManager`, etc.  However, we've started noticing logical deadlocks (in the .net code, not in SQL) when there are a lot of concurrent requests.

I've tracked down the problem to locking that is done by the `PropertyInterceptors`.  We use them quite extensively and have cases where the interceptor on one property (Property A) will set another property (Property B) but that the converse is also true (setting B will also set A).  The exact reasons for some of these cases are complicated but the basic idea is that we have some properties that we want to keep in sync.  It seems that there is locking inside the `PropertyInterceptor` logic so we can easily hit deadlocks because the order in which those locks are taken can vary.

I've created a simple reproducible case below that involves an Entity with just two properties.  One is an integer property and the other a string property.  I have `BeforeSet` logic to keep these two in sync with each other.  In the simple case of settings the properties one at a time, everything works.  But since we are dealing with a web api, it's very common for things to execute in parallel.  If we get one request that happens to set `IntValue` and another request that happens to set `StringValue`, we'll hit a deadlock.  This is true even though we are talking about two different entities in two different `EntityManager`s.  From our perspective, we are doing everything in a thread safe manner but then DevForce has some very long-lived locks which we know can be dangerous.

Here is the code which hopefully explains things.  Keep in mind our actual code is much more complicated but the basic deadlock is the same:

```
public static void ReproduceDeadlock()
{
    var e1 = new MyEntity();
    var e2 = new MyEntity();

    //This works - settings fields one at a time is fine
    e1.IntValue = 1;
    e2.StringValue = "2";

    //But if we introduce some concurrency, we'll become deadlocked
    Task.Run(() =>
    {
        //Wait a bit so e1.IntValue has a chance to start
        Thread.Sleep(1000);

        e2.StringValue = "22";
    });

    e1.IntValue = 11;

    //Execution will never make it hear...setting the IntValue will never complete
}

public class MyEntity : Entity
{
    [BeforeSet("StringValue")]
    public void BeforeSetStringValue(PropertyInterceptorArgs<MyEntity, string> args)
    {
        //When the string is set, 'sync' it to the IntValue property
        IntValue = int.Parse(args.Value);
    }

    [BeforeSet("IntValue")]
    public void BeforeSetIntValue(PropertyInterceptorArgs<MyEntity, int> args)
    {
        //When the int is set, 'sync' it to the StringValue property

        //Introduce a delay so the deadlock will obviously happen.  In our real app, we don't have
        //  a Thread.Sleep() but we do have non-trivial logic that can cause just enough delay for the deadlock
        //  to happen sometimes
        Thread.Sleep(2000);
        StringValue = args.Value.ToString();
    }

    #region PropertyMetadata stuff

    public class PropertyMetadata
    {
        public static readonly DataEntityProperty<MyEntity, string> StringValue =
            new DataEntityProperty<MyEntity, string>("StringValue", true, false,
                ConcurrencyStrategy.None, false, null,
                false);

        public static readonly DataEntityProperty<MyEntity, int> IntValue =
            new DataEntityProperty<MyEntity, int>("IntValue", true, false,
                ConcurrencyStrategy.None, false, null,
                false);
    }

    public string StringValue
    {
        get { return PropertyMetadata.StringValue.GetValue(this); }
        set { PropertyMetadata.StringValue.SetValue(this, value); }
    }

    public int IntValue
    {
        get { return PropertyMetadata.IntValue.GetValue(this); }
        set { PropertyMetadata.IntValue.SetValue(this, value); }
    }

    #endregion
}
```

}

Comment: It's going to be a few days before I can look into this.   The PropertyInterceptorManager is a singleton, so property interceptors are not local to an EntityManager.  Each PropertyInterceptor instance does lock for thread safety when executing, but I wonder if what's happening here is occurring during the discovery/initialization phase of the PropertyInterceptorManager.  This normally happens lazily, but you can force it by calling PropertyInterceptorManager.CurrentInstance.DiscoverInterceptorsFromAttributes().

Comment: OK, as you've found, the deadlock does occur when executing the interceptor actions, not at discovery/init time.  It looks like we need to use thread-local variables during PI execution, not locking.

Comment: That would be great.  Thread-local seems like a good solution.  I'm guessing there isn't really a workaround I can use now?  I tried a few things but nothing seemed to work.  And do you have a rough estimate as to when that fix might be available?

Comment: We've had performance issues with thread-local variables in the PropertyInterceptor class, so the solution may not be quite this simple.  The fix would probably be available mid-June, but if you need it sooner let me know, as I can't think of any workarounds either.

Comment: Just checking if the fix is still on schedule for mid-June?  The workaround you suggested won't really work for us so we're hoping for the full fix soon... :)

Comment: No, it won't be available that soon, as we were hoping the workaround would be sufficient and not require a product change.  We might be able to get you a beta early next week.

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more clear about the workaround thing.  Getting a beta next week would be great.  It's pretty easy to hit the deadlock for us so I should know pretty quickly if things are fixed for our use cases.

Comment: OK, please also take a look at the other workaround I've added in my answer.  Not that I'm not eager to dive into this very hairy piece of code, I'd just like to exhaust all possibilities.  :)

Answer (score 1):

Stephen, maybe I do have a workaround for you.  In the interceptor actions you can use SetValueRaw to sync the value to another property and avoid going through its interceptor (and validation).  The method is available on the public IStructuralObject interface, which, although documented as for internal use only, is not something we plan to change.  Both the EntityAspect and ComplexAspect classes implement this interface.

So your example would look like this:

```
[BeforeSet("StringValue")]
public void BeforeSetStringValue(PropertyInterceptorArgs<MyEntity, string> args)
{
    //When the string is set, 'sync' it to the IntValue property
    (this.EntityAspect as IStructuralObject).SetValueRaw(PropertyMetadata.IntValue, int.Parse(args.Value));
}

[BeforeSet("IntValue")]
public void BeforeSetIntValue(PropertyInterceptorArgs<MyEntity, int> args)
{
    //When the int is set, 'sync' it to the StringValue property

    //Introduce a delay so the deadlock will obviously happen.  In our real app, we don't have
    //  a Thread.Sleep() but we do have non-trivial logic that can cause just enough delay for the deadlock
    //  to happen sometimes
    Thread.Sleep(2000);

    (this.EntityAspect as IStructuralObject).SetValueRaw(PropertyMetadata.StringValue, args.Value.ToString());
}
```

I'll note one other workaround too.  The deadlock is in the interceptor, but you can have all the usual validation logic and change notification occur, just without the interception layer.  One way to do this is to set the EntityGroup.PropertyInterceptionEnabled flag to false, but it's usually pretty clumsy to turn this on and off.  Another option is a helper function to do exactly what the SetterInterceptor is doing:

```
public static void SetValueWithVerification(IStructuralObject so, DataEntityProperty property, object newValue)
{
    if (so.VerifierEngine != null && so.VerifierEngine.Enabled && so.EntityGroup.VerificationEnabled)
    {
        if ((property.MemberMetadata.VerifierSetterOptions & VerifierSetterOptions.BeforeSet) > 0)
        {
            so.ValidatePropertyBeforeSet(property, newValue);
        }

        so.SetValueWithChangeNotification(property, newValue);

        if ((property.MemberMetadata.VerifierSetterOptions & VerifierSetterOptions.AfterSet) > 0)
        {
            so.ValidatePropertyAfterSet(property, newValue);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        so.SetValueWithChangeNotification(property, newValue);
    }
}
```

Then call this in these tightly coupled interceptor actions:

```
SetValueWithVerification(this.EntityAspect, PropertyMetadata.StringValue, args.Value.ToString());
```

Comment: Thanks for the update.  On first thought, I don't think that will help.  We probably do want the interceptors/validations/etc. to still fire as part of syncing.  If there is a validation on `IntValue` and somebody sets `StringValue`, I still want there to be a validation error.  Also, we have a lot of logic in OnPropertyChanged and I'd still want that to fire.  But I'll take a look at this...maybe I can use this somehow...

Comment: I've tested this updated workaround and it seems like it will fix the one deadlock that we kept running into. This will work for us in the short-term but it doesn't seem like it is a good long-term solution. This one deadlock took so much time to troubleshoot and actually identify. If we saw another deadlock in production, it would be very painful. Also, we have hundreds of entities with tons of logic like this and there is no way we would be able to eagerly re-write all of that to use this workaround.

Comment: OK, thanks for trying it out.  We're still on schedule to give you a pre-release early next week.

Comment: That's great news.  I've been testing the workaround more and I've gotten less excited than I was yesterday.  The workaround obviously skips the interceptor actions but I realize we use those all over the place (and in places that I've forgotten)....so for now, I'm just going to wait until next week for the real fix.  Thanks!